# How to set "Ctrl + PlusSign" shortcut in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, shortcut

In VScode (actually Codium v1.38.1), I want to set up <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> as a shortcut for zoom in.

However, the key recorder doesn't allow me to do this.
I tried also to set this up in the JSON file as follows, but it doesn't work:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl++",
    "command": "workbench.action.zoomIn"
},
```

➥ How to set up this shortcut?

Comment: the default setting for zoom in is ctrl + + right?

Comment: @ng-suhas I have `{ "key": "ctrl+numpad_add",       "command": "workbench.action.zoomIn" },
{ "key": "ctrl+7",                "command": "workbench.action.zoomIn" },
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+=",          "command": "workbench.action.zoomIn" },
{ "key": "ctrl+=",                "command": "workbench.action.zoomIn" },` in the Default Keybinding JSON file. However, I don't have "numpad".

Comment: Are you trying to use the numpad?  You already appear to have `ctrl+shift+=` which is how you get to the `+` sign = with a shift.  And you have the simpler `ctrl+=`.  So it isn't clear what you are trying to do.